# Htaccess doesn't redirect as I need

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

thanks for reading!
I have a redirect in htaccess which redirects all the traffic to a folder /new except traffic from 111.111.111.111 that It is supossed to not redirect with this code, but doesnt work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myweb.org$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myweb.org$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.111.111.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

I want to go to [www.myweb.org](http://www.myweb.org) and not be redirect to /new folder, why is redirecting me? What is the error in this code? I will appreciate any help about this :)
Thank you very much in advanced!
Regards!

Comment: Test from command line curl to avoid browser cache and make sure Apache is getting same `REMOTE_ADDR` as in the rule

Comment: What other directives do you have? Have you confirmed that the server is seeing the IP address you are expecting (ie. you're not behind a proxy, load balancer, CDN, etc)?

Comment: Exact, my IP didn't match the remote IP that the server was reading. I have get this IP and change it in the code and all is right, thank you very much!!